# Syntax error checking in a Laravel controller

Tags: php, database, laravel, syntax

I have a syntax error in this code, but I can't find it.

I need to use the Laravel framework.

```
public function create() 

  {
    $users = User::where('user_type', 2)->get();
    $auto_email_templates=AutoEmailTemplate::all();


    foreach($auto_email_templates as $mail) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {

            if( $user->created_at < Carbon::now()->subDays($mail->days)){

                if (EmailSave::where('email_id','user_id')->count()< 1){

                    $mail = new EmailSave;
                    $mail->user_id = $user->id;
                    $mail->email_id =$mail->id;

                    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Automail($mail));

                    $mail->save();
                }                  
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Last Curly Brace is Missing

```
    public function create() 

      {
        $users = User::where('user_type', 2)->get();
        $auto_email_templates=AutoEmailTemplate::all();


        foreach($auto_email_templates as $mail) {
            foreach ($users as $user) {

                if( $user->created_at < Carbon::now()->subDays($mail->days)){

                    if (EmailSave::where('email_id','user_id')->count()< 1){

                        $mail = new EmailSave;
                        $mail->user_id = $user->id;
                        $mail->email_id =$mail->id;

                        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Automail($mail));

                        $mail->save();
                    }                  
                }
             }
          }
    } //you missed it
```

Answer (score 0):

Last two bracket was missing

```
  public function create() 

  {
    $users = User::where('user_type', 2)->get();
    $auto_email_templates=AutoEmailTemplate::all();


    foreach($auto_email_templates as $mail) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {

            if( $user->created_at < Carbon::now()->subDays($mail->days)){

                if (EmailSave::where('email_id','user_id')->count()< 1){

                    $mail = new EmailSave;
                    $mail->user_id = $user->id;
                    $mail->email_id =$mail->id;

                    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Automail($mail));

                    $mail->save();
                }                  
            }
         }
     }
 }
```